# NoSuchMethodError ClassTypeInformation.from

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, nosuchmethoderror

I have the following dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

however I am getting the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper.<clinit>(DefaultMongoTypeMapper.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.<init>(MappingMongoConverter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:1896)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:209)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:194)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration.mongoTemplate(MongoDataAutoConfiguration.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7ba1d827.CGLIB$mongoTemplate$1(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7ba1d827$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5c3e7e1e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7ba1d827.mongoTemplate(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 63 more
```

the from method should be present in those versions so I do not know how it is not found.
What dependency could cause this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: It look like you have old spring jars in your class path

Comment: In your ide, could you see the jar version ?

Comment: for which jar however?

Comment: all the dependencies listed in the pom.xml have the same version as listed in the pom

Comment: You've got two different versions of Spring Data Commons modules. Also, I don't think that's all of your dependencies. I can't see anything related to Spring Data Mongo but it's in the stack trace. Can you post the output of `mvn dependency:tree`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were in fact issues with dependency versions. I was having some dependencies imported from parent projects.

Thanks to @Naveen Ramawat and @Andy Wilkinson for the tips in the comments.